# How to setup servlet and jsp project in VScode IDE with Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, visual-studio-code

I want to create a simple web application using servlet and jsp with the help of youtube tutorials in vscode. I need to install and apache tomcat for this purpose. So, I have downloaded tomcat extension in my vscode and connected it with its directory that has tomcat in it in my pc. Tomcat server is working fine on my browser and I am also able to login in manager app with my credentials.

But I am little confused here. I already have liveserver extension on my vscode than why I need to install tomcat? and Should I create my project using maven-archetype-webapp or maven-archetype-j2ee-simple or with any other type? Please help with these doubts. I love vscode ide so, please come with a solution in vscode only.

Answer (score 1):

If Live Server can support your projects to run successfully, you don't need to install tomcat again.

[maven-archetype-j2ee-simple](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-j2ee-simple/) is an archetype which generates a simplified sample J2EE application.

[maven-archetype-webapp](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/) is an archetype which generates a sample Maven webapp project. Its folder structure is relatively simple when compared to maven-archetype-j2ee-simple. You can choose it depends on the complexity of the project you wanna develop.

Comment: Hi @Molly Wang, Could you please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351073/unable-to-run-simple-servlet-using-tomcat-server-in-vscode

Comment: This link hasn't accept answers. I've noticed you put another question:[Create a servlet in VScode maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356546/create-a-servlet-in-vscode-maven-project), so i follow up it.